# How to import js scripts from url using require

Tags: angular, opentok

I am trying to load an js file (https://static.opentok.com/v2.11/js/opentok.js) in an Angular2 component.

Is there any way to acheive this using "require()".

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. We recently released opentok.js on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opentok/client

You can do this:

```
var OT = require('@opentok/client');
var publisher = OT.initPublisher();
```

From then on you can use `OT` as you normally would.